# Bootstrap - Badge in Img mantain responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, responsive-design

I need a badge within an img - **independently from the window size** - So far I have in my html following code (btw. I'm using Angular - but framework should be irrelevant):

```css
.icon-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

troop-level-badge {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}
```

```html
`
<div class="container row" *ngIf="img">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <img class="rounded" [src]="img" width="40" height="auto">
      <span class="badge badge-dark troop-level-badge">6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

so far the result looks like this (as expected): [image: expected Version]

But when i resize the window the badge breaks out of the div. Does
someone know how i can contain the badge within the img even by resizing the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `troop-level-badge` rule isn't valid. There is a missing point. So replace `troop-level-badge` with `.troop-level-badge` and it should work like the following. To display the badge on the right side you need to set `right:2px;` instead of `left:2px;`:

```css
.icon-container {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.troop-level-badge {
  bottom:2px;
  position:absolute;
  right:2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container row" *ngIf="img">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="icon-container">
      <img class="rounded" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" >
      <span class="badge badge-dark troop-level-badge">6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <img class="rounded" src="https://placehold.it/75x75" >
      <span class="badge badge-dark troop-level-badge">6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <img class="rounded" src="https://placehold.it/50x50" >
      <span class="badge badge-dark troop-level-badge">6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```